# How to Query range in Cassandra

Tags: database, cassandra, nosql, cql

I’m trying to query a integer on Cassandra table and get the error `Only EQ and IN relation are supported on the partition key(unless you use the token()function)` My table is setup Is below with the query I ran. Be aware I did not setup the table nor can I change it currently.

```
CREATE TABLE USERS(
accName text,
accContext text,
accNumber int,
accCount int,
accHost text,
PRIMARY KEY (accName,accContext,accNumber)
);

SELECT * FROM Users WHERE accName = 'tear' and accContext = 'db1' 
   and accNumber> 20200101 and accNumber<= 202002018;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your post-edit query:

```
SELECT * FROM Users
    WHERE accName = 'tear' and accContext = 'db1' 
    and accNumber> 20200101 and accNumber<= 202002018;
```

...**works just fine**.  If you specify `accName` (partition key) and `accContext` (1st clustering key), you absolutely *can* run a range query on an integer, assuming that it is the *next* clustering key.  However, if you were to eliminate `accContext` from your query, **this would fail because you're not giving Cassandra enough information to efficiently retrieve the desired data.**

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE accNumber> 20200101 and accNumber<= 202002018;
```

So this was your query before being edited with a working solution.  And of course, you saw the error stating that range queries on partition keys only work with the `token` function.

**Why is that?**

You've probably heard that Cassandra requires a "query based" approach to data modeling.  This is because all data usually does not reside on a single node. 
 Cross-node queries are expensive.  Forcing range queries on partition keys via `token` gives you the tools to limit your query to a node that is responsible for a specific token range.  In your case, this works:

```
aaron@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT token(accname),accname FROM Users
    WHERE token(accname) <= -6425313154088713591
      AND token(accname) >  -7367992452875979971;

 system.token(accname) | accname
-----------------------+---------
  -6611994791738996364 |    tear

(1 rows)
```

Deconstructing what I did here, by using the `token` function in my SELECT, I can see what the token of the string "tear" is.  Next, I can query `system.peers` to see which node(s) are responsible for that token, as well as to get an idea of the exact token ranges the target nodes are responsible for.